# Access spring bean that is exposed using http invoker from GWT application

Tags: java, spring, gwt

Can I access spring bean that exposed using http invoker (server) from GWT application (client)?

If so is there any example / tutorial for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an application template for Spring-GWT apps available [here](http://bram.jteam.nl/index.php/2007/06/20/springone-2007-slides-sample-code/), that you may find useful. I haven't tried it out, but I believe it's implemented as a Maven archetype.

For more background on exactly what this template does for you, and how to integrate GWT with Spring, check out the following (video) [presentation](http://www.parleys.com/d/142).

Answer (score 2):

you can try my way of GWT and Spring integration: https://code.google.com/p/gspring.

It's simple and clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have very good experience with Spring4GWT. Did the entire integration in a about 30 minutes. (including ORM). I used this link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/gwt-2-spring-3-jpa-2-hibernate-35.html

Managed to integrate UI Binder into the stack too. Will be pushing in the code shortly to google code. (will come back to update the link here). But if you need it before that, please drop a note.